# JPA lazy fetch list invokes SELECT queries in setter

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization

There is a method which returns entity from database by JPA. This entity has list for other entities, fetch type is LAZY. When I want to add object to this list I got exception:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7242] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: An attempt was made to traverse a relationship using indirection that had a null Session.  This often occurs when an entity with an uninstantiated LAZY relationship is serialized and that lazy relationship is traversed after serialization.  To avoid this issue, instantiate the LAZY relationship prior to serialization.
```

So in order to overcome this I can initialize this list by doing `.size()` on it. The thing is I don't really need these objects to be fetched from database so I would like to do something like this:
`fetchedEntity.setMyLazyFetchList(new ArrayList<>());` which works fine. I can further access my list, but the problem is as following: set method invokes the same select queries as `fetchedEntity.getMyLazyFetchList().size()` does. These queries are useless as I set value to a new list, so why are they invoked?

**Method fetching entity**

```java
public Competitor findAndInitializeEmptyGroups(Integer idCompetitor) {
    Competitor entity = em.find(Competitor.class, idCompetitor);
    System.out.println("Before set ");
    entity.setGroupCompetitorList(new ArrayList<>());
    System.out.print("After set lazy list size ");
    System.out.print(entity.getGroupCompetitorList().size());

    return entity;
}
```

**Lazy fetch list field in entity (Competitor)**

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "idCompetitor")
private List<GroupCompetitor> groupCompetitorList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Second end relationship field (GroupCompetitor)**

```java
@JoinColumn(name = "id_competitor", referencedColumnName = "id_competitor")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Competitor idCompetitor;
```

What logs say:

```java
Info:   Before set
Fine:   SELECT id_group_competitor, id_competitor, id_group_details FROM group_competitor WHERE (id_competitor = ?)
bind => [43]
Fine:   SELECT id_group_details, end_date, start_date, version, id_competition, id_group_name FROM group_details WHERE (id_group_details = ?)
bind => [241]
...
many more SELECTs

Info:   After set lazy list size
Info:   0
```

After replacing line

```java
entity.setGroupCompetitorList(new ArrayList<>());
```

with

```java
entity.getGroupCompetitorList().size();
```

And logs (they are the same except the list now consists of fetched entities):

```java
Info:   Before set
Fine:   SELECT id_group_competitor, id_competitor, id_group_details FROM group_competitor WHERE (id_competitor = ?)
bind => [43]
Fine:   SELECT id_group_details, end_date, start_date, version, id_competition, id_group_name FROM group_details WHERE (id_group_details = ?)
bind => [241]
...
many more SELECTs

Info:   After set lazy list size
Info:   44
```

So my question is: why `SELECT` queries are invoked when I do `entity.setGroupCompetitorList(new ArrayList<>());`? I don't want them for the performance reasons. Is there any way to eliminate this issue or what exactly causes this behavior?

Using:

- EclipseLink JPA 2.1
- GlassFish 4.1
- Java 8

Comment: You are modifying/accessing the list which forces the query as JPA tracks any changes you make to the entity.  Eclipselink uses weaving that helps track changes, and so if you wish to bypass triggering the relationship, you may need to bypass its weaving.  see http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/concepts/app_dev007.htm and https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Disabling_Weaving_with_Persistence_Unit_Properties

Comment: Setting `<property name="eclipselink.weaving.changetracking" value="false"/>` or using `@ChangeTracking(DEFERRED)` in entity caused these SELECT queries not to be invoked during `set()`, but I noticed they are invoked during next EntityManager `flush()` so the performance did not improve, but thanks for links, they helped me understanding some things.

Comment: Are you trying to replace the list?  The JPA provider needs the list to know what references to remove in the database when you merge back into it.  If this is the case, you want to use weaving and change tracking.  EclipseLink can track additions to lists without having to fetch the full list when change tracking is enabled, as long as the Entity is attached to the context.  If you need to serialize the entity, it will need to be prefetched or you can't access the collection.

Comment: It was my flaw in thinking. I thought new objects are persisted through this list, but they weren't, So I don't need to add objects to this list because they are persisted later on their own. It's just bidirectional relationship for convenience and should be only read from. My entities are managed only in the method which I posted because I use EJB remote interfaces and everything is serialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can't not fetch a list that is a member of an entity if you want to add an element and have the JPA provider persist it.  The JPA provider has to track the owner, the ownee, and handle any cascading (which I don't see you have defined but I doubt there's a different code path for each combination of cascading options).  The simplest way would be to have the list in memory and then decide what operation to perform on the DB at commit/flush time.

I believe the cause of your original exception about traversing a LAZY is due to accessing outside on a managed context.  Once you return from an EJB method, the entity you're returning becomes detached.  You have to reattach it to another `EntityManager` or make sure all the lazy relationships you're about to use have been loaded before you leave the method.  Calling `fetchedEntity.getMyLazyFetchList().size()` would be an example of that and works fine in a single entity case.  If you want to force the load of a LAZY in a list of entities I suggest you read up on LEFT JOIN FETCH clauses.  I'm assuming here that your `findAndInitializeEmptyGroups()` method is in an EJB, judging by what looks to me like an injected `EntitManager em` in that method, and that the methods will get the default `@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED)` treatment since I don't see any annotations to the contrary.

Now, let's go back to your original problem:

> I want to add object to this list

The problem you're trying to solve is to add an element to a list without fetching the entire list.  You're using a `mappedBy` attribute, meaning you've created a bidirectional relationship.  If `getGroupCompetitorList()` returns an unordered list (a 'bag' in Hibernate speak) then you don't have to load the list at all.  Try something like this:

Change `GroupCompetitor`'s `Integer idCompetitor` to a `@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) Competitor competitor`.  Adjust the getters and setters accordingly.

Change `Competitor`'s `groupCompetitorList` `mappedBy` to `competitor`.  Add get/set methods.

Then you can add to the list from the child side with a method like this in the EJB:

```
public void addNewGroupCompetitorToCompetitor(Competitor comp, GroupCompetitor gComp) {
    gComp.setCompetitor(comp);
    em.persist(gComp);
    em.flush();
}
```

The next time you fetch the `Competitor` again it and traverse `entity.getGroupCompetitorList()` (while managed by an `EntityManager`) it should have the new `GroupCompetitor` you've added.  This kind of thing gets more complicated depending if `comp` is a new entity that has not been persisted, but that's the basic idea.  It might need some adjustment to work correctly with EclipseLink, but I do the same kind of operation with Hibernate as the JPA provider and it works.

Comment: I believe I already have your proposed solution, but my field names are misleading (idCompetitor is type of Competitor, not Integer - auto generated, didn't change that, added this field to my post). I wanted to be able to add new objects to list without need of fetching old/invoking database select queries. In fact I didn't have to add these objects to list because I persist them on their own, without cascading and the list is only needed for me to read from it, not adding new values.

Comment: Good.  I'm glad you were able to find a solution.  For reference though, there are times you may need to add it to the list.  If both parent and child (Competitor and GroupCompetitor in this case) are in memory and managed, flushing the new child will not update the parent's list.  The parent will only have the correct list if it is loaded after the transaction that added the child is complete.  When both are in memory, which I tend to do since rarely am I only adding an element to a list, my operations look like:
parent.getChildren().add(child);
child.setParent(parent);
em.flush();